# How to set attribute labels when using dynamic model in yii2 framework?

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

How to set attribute labels when using dynamic model in yii2 framework?

Here is my code below:

```
$model = DynamicModel::validateData(compact('name','shipping'), [
        [['name','shipping'], 'required'],
    ]);
    if ($model->hasErrors()) {
        // validation fails
      //  }
    } else {
        //validation true
    }
```

Comment: Hmm, looks like this is not possible as `attributeLabels()` is only a getter, not a setter. There was a (closed) issue on GitHub requesting such a feature; the comments suggest implementing your own `MyDynamicModel` class which allows for setting attribute labels. https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues/6420

Answer (score 6):

As a simple way out, just set separate validation messages for needed attributes:

```
$model = DynamicModel::validateData(compact('name','shipping'), [
    [['name'], 'required', ['message' => Yii::t('app', 'Name is required for this form.')]],
    [['name'], 'required', ['message' => Yii::t('app', 'Shipping address is required for this form.')]],
]);
```

And use labels when outputting DynamicModel field:

```
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput()->label(Yii::t('app', 'Name')); 
echo $form->field($model, 'name')->textInput()->label(Yii::t('app', 'Shipping address'));
```

Answer (score 0):

I like to extend the component, like this:

```
class DynamicModel extends \yii\base\DynamicModel {

    protected $_labels;

    public function setAttributeLabels($labels){
        $this->_labels = $labels;
    }

    public function getAttributeLabel($name){
        return $this->_labels[$name] ?? $name;
    }
}
```

And, to use it:

```
$attributes = ['name'=>'John','email'=>'john@mailinator.com'];
$model = new DynamicModel($attributes);
$model->setAttributeLabels(['name'=>'Name','email'=>'E-mail']);
$model->validate();
```

Comment: There is no need, both methods, available since version **yii 2.0.35**

Answer (score -2):

For example:

*model*

```
    public function attributeLabels()
    {
       return [
         'id' => Yii::t('app', 'ID'),
         'first_name' => Yii::t('app', 'First Name'),
      ];
   }
```

For more on [attributeLabels()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#attributeLabels%28%29-detail) and [generateAttributeLabel()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#generateAttributeLabel%28%29-detail)

Comment: The OP is not asking that.